# How to define the serialization id of the DefaultListableBeanFactory?

Tags: java, spring, session, serialization

I've got the serialization error with DefaultListableBeanFactory:

> ```
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: DefaultListableBeanFactory has no serialization id
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.writeReplace(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1523)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteReplace(ObjectStreamClass.java:1118)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1136)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>   at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1673)
>   at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1079)
>   at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:432)
>   at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
>   at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:518)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5622)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
>   ... 4 more
> ```

After inspecting the code I've found out, that the class code requires some arbirtrary serialization id to be set somewhere:

```
protected Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
    if (this.serializationId != null) {
        return new SerializedBeanFactoryReference(this.serializationId);
    }
    else {
        throw new NotSerializableException("DefaultListableBeanFactory has no serialization id");
    }
}
```

I'm not setting that serializationId, and I haven't found out, how can I set it. I suppose, something is missing in my spring xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.beans"/>

</beans>
```

The singleton beans are made serializable using aop scoped proxy:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES) 
public class DatabaseAPIImpl implements DatabaseAPI {
```

but obviously, something is wrong with that proxy and some crucial informations are not set. What I am missing here? What should I set so that the DefaultListableBeanFactory is properly initialized?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it doing this:

```
  @Component
  public class SessionFixBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
      private static final String SERIALIZATION_ID = "4086d293-966c-4d89-8485-f1c1f5c09218";

      @Override
      public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
          if ((beanFactory instanceof DefaultListableBeanFactory)) {
              DefaultListableBeanFactory dlbf = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
              dlbf.setSerializationId(SERIALIZATION_ID);
          }
      }
  }
```

You may want to read this question: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/799